# How to get Throughput and Delay in the results?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo, inet

I ran a simulation of the VEINS example in OMNET++ and in the results window under browse data, I cannot see the option of throughput or delay. What should I add in the code to include these in the results?

I there any other module I should add? If so how should go about that?

Comment: Can't you just estimate them yourself at your application level? Like keeping the history of incoming payloads per second and delays. You can measure delay by substracting the current time from payload timestamp that is set in your packet with the following:
`payload->addTag<CreationTimeTag>()->setCreationTime(simTime());`

Comment: I was able to calculate the delay, but manually calculating throughput is giving me some absurd values. thank you!